# Traversing through Cloned records in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where I have a Service ID and that Service ID may be cloned for'N' times and I am supposed to pull out the last Cloned ID, Original Service ID and its related date details. I have added the sample table structure and my corrent query in the below rextester demo link.

Rextester link: https://rextester.com/WCM88976

Desired output:

[image: Traversing thro rec]

Any help?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this sample data, you can use `with ties` and a sub-query.

```
select top 1 with ties
    t.cid
    ,t.cvid
    ,clone = (select max(t2.cvid) from #temp1 t2 where t2.cid = t.cid)
    ,t.date1
from #temp1 t
order by row_number() over (partition by cid order by date1)
```

The `with ties` and `order by` is for other data, naturally.

Comment: Thanks. I was using CTEs for this and the run time was so long. This helped me :)

Comment: No sweat at all @Rick